# Link broken in inline comment

Tags: org-mode, debugging, org-link

```org
[[link]]@@comment:[[link]]@@
# [[link]]

* link
```

I get the message "No Link Found" when clicking on the `[[link]]` within the inline `@@comment:[[link]]@@`.

The link works fine with `emacs -Q`, but breaks after evaluating some `init.el` code. Problem is, I cannot pinpoint to the exact code that broke the link.

Evaluating the code from Castlemacs below, for example, could bring about the error.

```elisp
;; ====
;; INIT

;; Package system and sources.
(require 'package)
(let* ((no-ssl (and (memq system-type '(windows-nt ms-dos))
                 (not (gnutls-available-p))))
    (proto (if no-ssl "http" "https")))
    ;; Comment/uncomment these two lines to enable/disable MELPA and MELPA Stable as desired
    ;; (add-to-list 'package-archives (cons "melpa" (concat proto "://melpa.org/packages/")) t)
    (add-to-list 'package-archives (cons "melpa-stable" (concat proto "://stable.melpa.org/packages/")) t)
    (when (< emacs-major-version 24)
    ;; For important compatibility libraries like cl-lib
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . (concat proto "://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))))

(package-initialize)


;; We will use 'use-package' to install and configure packages.
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))
(eval-when-compile (require 'use-package))


;; No need to out 'ensure' everywhere, since we don't use anything else to install packages.
(setq use-package-always-ensure t)


;; Pass system shell environment to Emacs. This is important primarily for shell inside Emacs, but also things like Org mode export to Tex PDF don't work, since it relies on running external command pdflatex, which is loaded from PATH.
(use-package exec-path-from-shell
  :ensure t)
(when (memq window-system '(mac ns))
  (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))


;; Store custom-file separately, don't freak out when it's not found
(setq custom-file "~/.emacs.d/custom.el")
(load custom-file 'noerror)


;; Set path for private config. private.el is not part of Castlemacs and you can use it for your personal
;; additions. Do not change init.el yourself, it will make updates harder.
(add-hook
 'after-init-hook
 (lambda ()
   (let ((private-file (concat user-emacs-directory "private.el")))
     (when (file-exists-p private-file)
       (load-file private-file)))))
```

Comment: Emacs version 26.3

Comment: Even if you figure out how to unbreak it in that version, you will find it broken again in subsequent versions (9.1.14 and later). In particular, commit [d3774fba77fedac31bb9f291b3b06802c021de51](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/d3774fba77fedac31bb9f291b3b06802c021de51) has limited the opening of links in certain contexts (this one in particular).

Comment: BTW, `@@comment: foo @@` is not an inline comment (something which AFAIK Org mode does not support), it is an [export snippet](https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-syntax.html#Export_Snippets) for a hypothetical (and AFAIK non-existent) export backend, called `comment'.